# jQuery Datatables - Table header from AJAX response

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am retrieving a dataset that will include different lengths of rows via the Datatables ajax request. For example, one response might be:

```
... ['jan', 'feb', 'march', 'april'] ...
```

where as a different response would only be:

```
... ['jan', 'feb'] ...
```

Most examples that I have seen have the table headers already hard-coded into the HTML. What I want to do is to dynamically update the headers and their respective column data.

I was hoping to be able to do something like this where I am able to update the headers with dataSrc, but by that time the datatable has already been created and fails to fill in the rest of the table correctly.

```
....
table = $('#datatables').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/foo/bar/",
        "type": "GET",
        dataSrc: function (json) { 
            populate_table_header(json)
            return json.blah;
        }
},
...
```

I am perfectly ok with destroying and re-creating the table, I just need to know how to create the table while using the AJAX response data for new headers.

### Edit

Here's an example

```
   {  
  "data":[  
     ...
     [  
        "8290808-123123",
        "Boo Far",
        "bar@fu.com",
        "Other",
        "12",
        "21390",
        "123",
        "-",
        "-"
     ],
     [  
        "123123-032489",
        "Foo Bar",
        "foo@bar.com",
        "Name",
        "1",
        "2",
        "50",
        "-",
        "-"
     ],
     ...
  ],
  "header":[  
     "Owner",
     "Subscription",
     "Oct '16",
     "Nov '16",
     "Dec '16",
     "Jan '17",
     "Feb '17"
  ],


}
```

Is this possible without making a separate AJAX call before initializing the datatable?

Comment: You probably need to interrogate the data before initialising the DataTable and there define your `columns` before populating the table with data. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, makes sense. I was just hoping not to have to make the AJAX request outside of the datatables initialization.

Comment: It's sort of possible (I think, anyway) but a bit of a faff and I've not tested it with your data, perhaps if you provide a richer example of the data you want to display we can take a look?

Comment: example of the data has been added.

Comment: Bear with, will have a look in a little while.

Comment: I've looked and looked and it doesn't seem to be possible without destroying the table and recreating it. I think the best option is to create the table in your ajax return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this answers.
[datatables.net](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29260/dynamic-column-headers-via-ajax)

allan's say

> Good to hear you got it working :-)

If you can not solve the problem like this add live jsfidde demo to may helpfull you.
Good luck with job.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw that post earlier but was hoping to not have to have to make the AJAX request outside of the datatables initialization. Seems like that might not be possible, though.

Comment: Maybe it is possible but I do not know a easy method of this. If you take a look at the datatables.js debug mode, you have a very complex and modular structure :D sorry. I have't premium support from datatables.net. You can use destroy - init method if it is not causing a huge performance problem.